# Не выбираются уникальные записи

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется следующая таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE station_references (
  ID MEDIUMINT    UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
  Code            CHAR(7) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  NameRu          VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  PopularityIndex SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  Description     VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  IsActive        BIT(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Пример заполнения таблицы:

```
INSERT INTO station_references
(Code, NameRu, PopularityIndex, Description, IsActive) 
('2000000', 'Москва', 257, '', true),
('2004484', 'Москаленки', 54, '', true),
('2004468', 'Мостовая', 80, '', true);
```

Нужно показать список городов, которые начинаются с подстроки, либо содержат подстроку. Те города, которые начинаются с подстроки, должны показаться выше чем те что содержат.

Написал такой запрос такой запрос:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Code, NameRu, PopularityIndex FROM (
  SELECT ID, Code, NameRu, 200 + PopularityIndex as PopularityIndex, IsActive
    FROM station_references
    WHERE NameRu LIKE 'мос%'
  UNION -- // или даже UNION DISTINCT
  SELECT ID, Code, NameRu, PopularityIndex, IsActive
    FROM station_references
    WHERE NameRu LIKE '%мос%'
) A
WHERE IsActive = true
ORDER BY PopularityIndex DESC
limit 8;
```

В выборке 2 раза встречается запись с одним и тем же айдишником не смотря на все DISTINCT.
Ожидаемый результат:

```
Москва 457
Мостовая 280
Москаленки 254
```

Полученный результат:

```
Москва 457
Мостовая 280
Москва 257
Москаленки 254
```

Пока что решаю проблему, записав условие во втором SELECT следующим образом

```
WHERE NameRu LIKE '%мос%' AND NameRu NOT LIKE 'мос%'
```

Но блин выгляди как костыль.

Как можно отсечь повторяющиеся записи в этом примере?

Comment: Добавьте CREATE TABLE и INSERT INTO с примером данных (или создайте online fiddle), и покажите нужный результат для этих данных.

Comment: *Те города, которые начинаются с подстроки, должны показаться выше чем те что содержат.* `ORDER BY NameRu NOT LIKE 'мос%'`

Comment: @Akina по поводу order by - к сожалению это не решает проблемы повторной выборки одних и тех же записей

Comment: группируйте по названию, выбирайте максимальный индекс тогда. distinct вам не даст ожидаемого, поскольку индекс в строках-повторах разный. Если не будете вытаскивать popularityInex то повторов не будет.

Comment: а по поводу `order by` то там юнион просто не нужен. оставьте только `like %мос%`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM station_references
WHERE LOCATE(@pattern, NameRu)
ORDER BY LOCATE(@pattern, NameRu);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e69dc6d5e0a36196ad22a2dc3b1cd93b)